# Resizing images in Python 3.4

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

Okay, maybe I'm missing something here, but where is the image library for Python 3.4?

According to the [PIL download page](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/), not only is it surprisingly unmaintained (No updates in five years?) but also, it doesn't support Python 3.x

> The current free version is PIL 1.1.7. This release supports Python 1.5.2 and newer, including 2.5 and 2.6. **A version for 3.X will be released later.**

So did I find the wrong, or outdated page (that one wasn't obvious to find, but it's the only download page I could find), or are Python 3.x users stuck with no image library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.6.1) instead. This is a fork of PIL and it's maintained with support for Python 3.x.